# Is there a cross platform c++ serial port library that can enumerate ports?

Tags: c++, serial-port, cross-platform

I am looking for a c++ library that can connect to and communicate with serial port devices. I need one that can be used on windows and linux. I have found "serialib" already but this has no feature for enumerating the available ports.

So I either need a cross platform "port enumerator" library or a whole new cross platform serial port library.

Does anyone know of a good one?

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  The days that you could plug a serial cable into a clearly labeled connector in the back of the machine are long over.  You can get a list of available ports with a native call but that still doesn't tell you which of those ports is actually connected to the device.  The user is going to have to figure this out.  Provide him with a config file that allows him to enter the port name.  Now it doesn't matter anymore what specific format for the port name is used.

Comment: Having to write a port name in a config file is an inconvenience. I have seen cross platform applications that enumerate usable/connected ports and provide a list for the user. This is what I want. (a good example is the Arduino IDE, this is written in java however.)

Comment: You found a cross-platform library for Arduino?  Of course it is an inconvenience to the user.  Serial ports date from the seventies, forty year old hardware that doesn't support plug and pray.  The mistake here is to rely on a forty year old hardware standard.  And yes, probably not your fault, some hardware vendor chose the easy route.  Find another vendor.

Comment: FTDI chips like the one found on an arduino provide USB access to a serial port on a chip like the ATMega328 in the Arduino, serial communication isn't outdated, almost all microcontrollers have TX and RX pins. USB definately isn't outdated. The FTDI drivers provide you with a serial connection just like a hardware serial port would, this is fully supported by ALL modern OSes. I am not using an outdated technology. I don't mind creating my own lib with #IFDEFs for each OS's unique method, so I guess that I should ask what's the best way for each OS?
Thanks, Dan.

Comment: The FTDI driver is quite notorious.  The resellers refuse to support it and FTDI won't publish the source code to give anybody a chance to improve it.  Probably because they don't own it.  Dadum.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 8):

http://wjwwood.io/serial/

https://github.com/wjwwood/serial

This is a cross-platform serial port library, which is MIT licensed and has no external dependencies for runtime.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like just the sort of thing I was after. I have already started using the one here though: http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/ and that works fine for me.

Comment: About [http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232](http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232):<br/>
_"It uses polling to receive characters from the serial port. Interrupt/event-based is not supported."_
<br/>
Any other options without the aforementioned restrictions?

Comment: Unfortunately the library is pretty careless about memory allocations, leaks, throwing exceptions, locking and as far as I can see does not support async IO.

Comment: @Trass3r which library is careless? teuniz RS-232 or wjwwood serial?

Comment: The wjwwood library.

Comment: >60 undressed issues in github, could not even install it with make

Answer (score 2):

The [QextSerialPort](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) project is a cross-platform serial port library that includes port enumeration. [Here](http://docs.qextserialport.googlecode.com/git/1.2/examples-enumerator-main-cpp.html) is their example of doing a simple enumeration of all serial ports.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not sure this is quite what I'm looking for as I'm not using Qt.

Comment: Fair enough, but keep in mind you don't need to any of use Qt's GUI facilities. The QtCore library (all that's needed to use QextSerialPort) only depends on Glib and PCRE.

Comment: I've had errors over errors trying to integrate QextSerialPort into e.g. Eclipse instead of QtCreator