# Windows equivalent of Canonical Mode Linux Serial Port

Tags: winapi, serial-port

I was wondering if their is an Windows equivalent of Canonical Mode Linux Serial Port.
I am developing a cross-platform serial port application that will read data line by line.
In Linux we have Canonical Mode to achieve the same. What is its (Canonical Mode's) equivalent in Windows?

I'm using Boost Asio serial port routines. I am getting the native handle and manually accessing and configuring the `termios` structure in Linux and `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure in Windows

Comment: Whether you want to achieve serial port read line in Windows? If so, I suggest you could try to use `com port`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the same. In my C/C++ program I have to handle reading input/data in line by line fashion or bulk data based on timeout.

Comment: What about using a library that declares itself cross-platform instead of conforming to the linux spec? [Is there a cross platform c++ serial port library that can enumerate ports? \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11467054/9014308)